# call avio_open function with non-english filename is invalid

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav, libavformat

i have been writing unicode based program with libav and i wanna make some file through libav with filename "中.mp4".

this filename is not english, and when i call, function return positive integer(not fail).

but there is "ѱ۰.mp4" instead of "中.mp4". (invalid file name.)

what's the matter?

```
char * szFilenameA = 0;

#ifdef _UNICODE
    CSHArray<char> aFilenameBuffer;
    aFilenameBuffer.Alloc(lstrlen(szFileName) * 2);
    ZeroMemory(aFilenameBuffer, aFilenameBuffer.GetSize());
    WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, szFileName, lstrlen(szFileName), aFilenameBuffer, aFilenameBuffer.GetSize(), NULL, NULL);
    szFilenameA = aFilenameBuffer;
#else
    szFilenameA = (TCHAR *)szFileName;
#endif

    ZeroMemory(m_pOutputFormatCtx->filename,1024);
    _snprintf(m_pOutputFormatCtx->filename, strlen(szFilenameA), "%s", szFilenameA);

    avio_open(&m_pOutputFormatCtx->pb, szFilenameA, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally!
it's because of charset.

convert ansi filename to UTF8 and then it works fine.

```
int ANSIToUTF8(char *pszCode, char *UTF8code)
{
  WCHAR Unicode[100]={0,}; 
  char utf8[100]={0,};

  // read char Lenth
  int nUnicodeSize = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, pszCode, strlen(pszCode), Unicode, sizeof(Unicode)); 

  // read UTF-8 Lenth
  int nUTF8codeSize = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, Unicode, nUnicodeSize, UTF8code, sizeof(Unicode), NULL, NULL); 

  // convert to UTF-8 
  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, utf8, nUTF8codeSize, Unicode, sizeof(Unicode)); 
  return nUTF8codeSize;
}
```